# How to unit test Vue component that append DOM-element to HTML body?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I have a Vue 2.0 component that uses the Menu component from [Vuetify](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/). I'm using the official [vue-test-utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org) to mount my component during test.

The problem I'm facing is that the Menu component append the "menu" to the HTML-body (outside the scope of the component). Because of that I cant access it with `wrapper.find('.menu')` like i would with any other element in my component.

Is there a good way to access an element appended to the body using vue-test-utils?

**Update**

My component at this point looks pretty much exactly like this [Vuetify codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZoWjK)

And I mount my component something like this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import AuthenticatedUser from './AuthenticatedUser'
import { mount, createLocalVue } from 'vue-test-utils'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(Vuetify)

describe('AuthenticatedUser', () => {
  let getters
  let store

  beforeEach(() => {
    getters = {
      getUserDetails: () => { name: 'John Doe' }
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({ getters })
  })

  it('should open menu when button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(AuthenticatedUser, { store, localVue })

    // In here 'wrapper' won't have access to the dropdown menu,
    // since it has been added directly to the HTML body
  })
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your component definition, add a `ref` attribute to the content of the menu, in your case, the `<v-card>` component:

```
<v-menu>
  <v-btn slot="activator"></v-btn>
  <v-card ref="menu"></v-card>
</v-menu>
```

Then you'll be able to access that `<v-card>` component via `wrapper.vm.$refs.menu` in your test cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Added `ref="menu"` to `<v-card>` but `wrapper.$refs` is undefined in my test.

Comment: Ok maybe try `wrapper.vm.$refs.menu`. `vue-test-utils` is a bit outside my scope of knowledge

Comment: @thanksd I can able to access `wrapper.vm.$refs.menu` but if I want to trigger a click on a menu item, how it can be done?

Comment: Hi @VivekVikranth, I've been struggling to make similar tests, have you figured out the way to trigger a click on the menu item?

Comment: Also having this issue. Would like to be able to get the DOM content of the refs and to trigger events on them, not sure if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

How about using the attach property of the v-menu component, to apend the menu items inside the tested component?